# SP2007 Reasons why Item Created workflows Error, but when Restart they run to completion perfectly?

Tags: 2007, designer-workflow, updatelistitems

I have a very basic form. The user creates a nomination for another user. When the item is created the workflow does the following:

1. Make some simple checks to make sure the nominee or approver is not the Creator
2. Once checked an email is sent to the Approver and the status (a drop down on the form) is switched to "Sent for approval"
3. Workflow then "Waits for Field Change" on the Approval status changing to anything other than "Sent for approval".

The workflow creates an error at the log message prior to the Wait action. The email to the approver, which is actually about 3 actions prior to the Wait action never goes to the Approver.

The Approver is meant to follow a link in the email to the form and they are supposed to simply change the drop down value from "Sent for approval" to either "Decline" or "Approve". The workflow should then continue with the process.

However, it always errors as described. However, as soon as I manually cancel the workflow and start it again, the entire workflow, the entire process, works flawlessly.

I know we are using the worst version of SP available, but this error is making my job more difficult than it should be and I simply cannot find a reason for this error.